# Does NHibernate support subqueries in the `from` clause?

Tags: nhibernate, hql

Does NHibernate support subqueries in the `from` clause? For example I have sql queries looking like this:

```
SELECT subquery.Id, sum(subquery.Value) ... 
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Id, Value, ... FROM table1) as subquery
WHERE ...
GROUP BY subquery.Id
```

I've only found this info:

> HQL does not have subquery in from clause support.  I've been consider
>   how to add this, but I think it's going to be a substantial effort.
>   It's coming, but unless somebody can provide more development time,
>   it's going to take while to implement.
>           Patrick Earl

from [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nhusers/mCJ_fOC_wfo) (17.08.2011). Is it still relevant? Maybe I can use Linq to NHibernate?

Comment: what version of nhibernate are you on??

Comment: also why do you need want to write in HQL you, dont stand to gain any advantage out of it, why dont you just run the sql query??

Comment: @Baz1nga. I'm using NHibernate 3.2. Plain SQL is unfortunately not allowed (application's database independence is required).

Answer (score 0):

If this functionality is not provided you could create a database view that does this and map your nhibernate entity to the database view.